# control web browsers using java program

Tags: c#, java, browser

I have an application written using C#.
it controls the browsers
it allows which pages to view and not to view and also it hides the address bar of IE.
I want to convert it to Java.
But I really dont know what API to use etc... .
can someone guide me for that.

thank you

Comment: :), does it seems like a poetry... very funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

OSS:
Native Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/

Commercial:
ICEBrowser  http://www.icesoft.org/

Comment: thanks... you save my time, but I dont know how icebrowser works

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://watij.com/
It is based on watir for ruby and watin for c#.

Comment: I am not sure wheather thats the one I am looking for, I want to control from outside the browsers...

Comment: SO could I be able to stop someone accesing the www.someweb.com from a browser using watij java program...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you were able to "control the browser" with C# using the Microsoft WebBrowser class, right?  The WebBrowser uses ActiveX to control Internet Explorer ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx)

If that is the case, for you to do the same, you need some way to connect Java and the ActiveX control. From what I could find on google, this might be your best bet:

Java COM ActiveX Bridge: http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/

Comment: what about other browsers then such as firefox, chrome and safari

Comment: Look at the source code for the Selenium project.  It is an automated regression testing tool, but it controls different browsers to do that: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Which_browsers_does_WebDriver_support? 
You can look at the code to see how Selenium controls the different browsers.  Good luck.